# Android AsyncTask return value

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
final Dialog Alert_Dialog = new Dialog(MainList.this);
Alert_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
Alert_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_progressbar);
((TextView)Alert_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage)).setText(R.string.please_wait_);
Alert_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
Alert_Dialog.show();
((Button) Alert_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Alert_Dialog.cancel();
   }
});
```

Then callin AsynTask like :

```
String res="";
try{
    SendingWebPageTask sendMaster=new SendingWebPageTask();
    res=sendMaster.execute(UrlMaster).get();
}catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i am returning value which url responding me on the base of responce i am calling second url but the problem it that when i am returning value from async task in this way it will not display an dialogbox and it will hang device till asynTask cannot complete its task so can any one help me.

Comment: so anyother way to display progress bar and return value from AsyncTask?

Comment: @PankajKumar what ??without solution i am right?

Comment: `so anyother way to display progress bar and return value from AsyncTask` isn't a solution sir?

Comment: now you had starting joking over here..

Comment: :D ok. I would suggest you to call asynctask from dialog, (at the same place where you canceled the dialog) and then update value of `res` on postexecute of asyntask...... now this is not a joke...

Answer (score 4):

In here:

```
res=sendMaster.execute(UrlMaster).get(); //<<<
```

you are calling [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) method on UI Thread instead of on other thread so this will freeze UI until `doInBackground` execution  is not completed and then get result back to main ui Thread.

**Option 1#**

you will need to use `onPostExecute` for updating UI when doInBackground execution complete because onPostExecute always called on UI thread. for showing  `ProgressDialog`  you can use `onPreExecute()` which called before stating background task

**Option 2#**

call `AsyncTask.get()` inside a Thread for getting results from doInBackground and use 
[Activity.runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for updating UI from non UI Thread

Comment: Thanks for your reply but on the resulet of 1st async task i am calling second url in this case i have to use .get to return value if i cannot use .get() then in second url it will pass null value

Comment: @Pankaj : ok then see second Option 2 in my answer

Comment: ok but i cannot do this with AsyncTask? becasuse in Runnable UiThread there is chanse of ANR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 class SendingWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
                private Dialog alertDialog;
                private boolean shouldCallTheSecondURL = false;

                public SendingWebPageTask(boolean shouldCallSecondURL) {
                     this.shouldCallSecondURL = shouldCallSecondURL;
                }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
               alertDialog = new Dialog(MainList.this);
    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog_progressbar);
    ((TextView)alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage)).setText(R.string.please_wait_);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.show();
    ((Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
       }
    });
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //TODO your code in background...
                            return result;//result is in String format
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            //dismiss the alertDialog after the task finish his background work
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.d("SendingWebPageTask", "result task : "+result);
                            String secondUrl = result;
                            if(shouldCallSecondURL)
                                new SendingWebPageTask(false).execute(secondUrl); 
            }
        }
```

for the fisrt call of your `AsyncTask` :

```
SendingWebPageTask sendMaster=new SendingWebPageTask(true);//passing true , so the asyncTask will launch another asynctask for the secondURL retreived from onPostExecute()
sendMaster.execute(UrlMaster);
```

Comment: i had tried this also but on the base of calling first url i am returning value and on return value i am calling second url in this way i have to return value from asynk task so this solution doesnt work in my case

Comment: so , in the `onPostExecute()` method you can execute your `AsyncTask` again, and pass to it the second url that you got from the first call of the asyncTask. see my edits

Comment: i am continiosly sending data to web server when i call url it will give me reply if it is successfuly store then i am calling second or third url in this way how can i use onPostExecute()??

Comment: Thanksf for this but i have more data inshort i am retriving data from my sqlite and storing on webserver so when i store 1st data it will respond me. on the base of respoce i am sending next to next data

Comment: all that treatment you can do it into onPostExecute, you can test your result and check if you should execute the AsyncTask again ,with the next data to send to server, or not